# Is it possible to reference an SDK ( or any folder ) in a Docker Container from the Host computer?

Tags: docker

Short description:
Is it possible to reference an SDK ( or any folder ) in a Docker Container from the Host computer?

Long description:
My team and I work in different environments ( Windows & Mac ) and on different stacks ( Asp .Net MVC / Elixir & Phoenix )
I'm trying to help everyone by creating separate Docker Stacks for each solution ( or group of projects )

What I have been able to do is set up the Docker Stacks so that each solution can be run in 1 or more Docker Containers and the developers can work on the code locally ( using direct host path mounts/volumes ) using an IDE of their choosing.
The issue is different solutions use different SDKs or even different versions of the same SDKs.

So what I would like to do is it up so that anyone in the team could reference the SDK installed on the Docker Container instead of installing the SDKs and each version of the SDKs they need for all the projects.
As far as I can tell, if I create a host mount binding, it will overwrite what's in the container with what's in the host, but I'd like to do it the other way round, I'd like to create a binding between the Docker Container and the Host and have the contents in the Docker Container show up in the Host.
Is this possible? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

SDK images from vendors (e.g. asp.net core SDK images from Microsoft) best recommended `compile/build` time purpose and its lightweight version recommended for `runtime` in hosting/deployment environment.

Sole purpose of compile/build SDK images is for creating docker runtime images at build stage especially if target runtime OS (linux) is different than development machine OS e.g. Windows. If used efficiently with [multistage builder pattern](https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/advanced-multi-stage-build-patterns-6f741b852fae) inside `dockerfile`, can create much lightweight runtime images for hosted environments.

e.g. `aspnet.core SDK` images used for building docker images and then run locally with host:guest port mapping. But if the dev machine OS is any linux distro then using SDK images is better as you can test validate in multiple SDK images. And these images just need exact name and docker deamon would download auto and use whenever required - that's it but certainly would needs good IDE orchestration support e.g. Visual Studio provides for docker based development on windows 10. or-else simply use docker CLI for build run.

Hope this helps clarify your need if not a solution